# Error al eliminar llave foránea

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy tratando de eliminar mi FOREIGN KEY, esto lo realizo desde la apex de oracle con el siguiente comando (que se supone alteraria la tabla):

```
ALTER TABLE TELEFONOS DROP FOREIGN KEY 'LLAVEFORANEA';
```

Pero al correrlo me sale este mensaje de error:
[image: Imagen recortada del error]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. 
Por favor, procura poner el código y los errores como texto, pues replicar tu problema desde una imagen es mucho más demorado y hace más difícil que te ayuden. De paso, esta imagen está para gente joven que puede leer letras diminutas :)
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saludos como lo que quieres eliminar es la llave forranea deberías hacerlo con `drop constraint` porque lo que quieres eliminar es la restricion de llave foranea, mas o menos te quedaría así tu codigo, espero que te funcione,

```
ALTER TABLE TELEFONOS DROP CONSTRAINT 'NOMBRE DE LA LLAVE FORANEA';
```

Comment: por qué piensas que lo que quiere es eliminar la columna?, la pregunta habla sólo de la llave foránea

Comment: Edite la pregunta creo que eso le debe ayudar

Comment: veo que editaste tu respuesta, pero ahora el código (que hace lo que creo que el op quiere) no se condice con la explicación de tu respuesta

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por la respuesta, soy algo nuevo en el tema, pude eliminar la llave con el codigo de la respuesta

Comment: Que bueno que te alla funcionado